# Get sample data with stream analytics

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I am using continuous export and stream analytics for a Power BI report. But I have some problems configuring the inputs for stream analytics.

Continuous export writes data to a blob storage.

But when I click on "sample data" I got the error message:

> "No events were found in 'input' for the specified time range".

But I am sure there is data stored for this time range.

My path prefix pattern looks like:

`application insights resource_keywithoutdashes/Requests/{date}/{time}`

My application insights resource has a whitespace and I have everything in lowercases.

I followed these steps: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-export-power-bi/

When I inspect the blob where the data is stored I see the container named "stats". This container has a folder named "application insights resource_keywithoutdashes" and this folder has a folder Requests, in that folder there are folders for every day since I started Continuous export. This folders are named like "2016-10-04" and these have folders named 00, 01, 02 to 23.

I tried to change the path prefix pattern to "stats/application insights resource_keywithoutdashes/Requests/{date}/{time}" but then I got the error message: "Failed to sample data from 'export-input'." and in the details i got: "Operation Failed Unexpectedly. Activity Id: 'xxx'".

When I click test connection I always get the message "Successfully connected to 'input'"

Why can't I get sample data? What am I doing wrong? Do I miss something?
Does anyone has some tips about how to configure this settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page was helping me out:

http://fabriccontroller.net/connecting-auth0-to-power-bi-with-stream-analytics-and-a-webtask/

On that page I found this full url and I found that I was looking at the wrong storage account.

> `https://{YOUR_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net/{YOUR_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME}/YYYY/MM/DD/HH/{LOG_ID}.json`